# Copy/Paste filepath from Nautilus/Files in Ubuntu does not work anymore

Tags: visual-studio-code

Since the last VSC update the convenient copy/paste of filepaths into a python file in VSC does not work anymore.

Reproduce:

- Selecting a file in Files/Nautilus
- `CTRL-C`
- Open python file in VSC
- `CTRL-V`

This pastes only the the filename without the path, e.g. only `somefile.txt` instead of `/home/rolle/tmp_files/somefile.txt`. Pasting this into GEdit works as exptected with the full path.

Is there a solution for this?

VSC: 1.67.1,
Ubuntu: 18.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works again for me in version 1.80.2